# mysql IF - ELSE statement in a select TIMESTAMPDIFF function

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table `employees` with a start_date and a end_date:

```
name  | start_date | end_date
John  | 1999-01-15 | NULL
Peter | 1995-05-12 | 2010-09-12
```

I have to calcalate the current working years:

- John has NOT leaved the company, so his working years until today are: 21 years
- Peter has leaved the company, so his years until 2010 are: 14

I am searching for a query like:

```
// Not working!!
SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, start_date, IFNULL(end_date, CURDATE()) AS difference FROM `employees`
```

But  this is not working... Anybody?

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: What is the output you are getting

Comment: My output is an error: #1064 - 'AS difference FROM `employees`'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

closing bracket missing after CURDATE() `)`

```
SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, start_date, IFNULL(end_date, CURDATE())) AS difference 
FROM `employees`
```

Comment: aaah... you are right... Thanks!

Comment: A typo is a reason for a question to be closed.